# How do i plot candlestick chart using matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

How do i plot candlestick chart using matplotlib? I can't find example for it, using mlp_finace package. I don't want to use matplotlib.finance package because it is deprecated.